# Error on generate scaffolds with references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I'm trying to generate 3 scaffolds:

> $ rails g scaffold Artist name:string type:string bio:text resume:string
>    site:string
>
> $ rails g scaffold ArtistSerie title:string artist:references
>
> $ rails g scaffold ArtistSeriePhoto photo:string
>    title:string year:integer description:text dimensions:string
>    featured:boolean artist_serie:references

the first two models are creating their indexes and foreign keys properly, but the third one is generating this error after `rake db:migrate`:

```
Mysql2::Error: Key column 'artist_series_id' doesn't exist in table: ALTER TABLE `artist_serie_photos` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_9422e9e931`
FOREIGN KEY (`artist_series_id`)
  REFERENCES `artist_series` (`id`)
```

here is the generated migrations:

```
class CreateArtists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :artists do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.text :bio
      t.string :resume
      t.string :site

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateArtistSeries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :artist_series do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :artist, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateArtistSeriePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :artist_serie_photos do |t|
      t.string :photo
      t.string :title
      t.integer :year
      t.text :description
      t.string :dimensions
      t.boolean :featured
      t.references :artist_serie, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

the table was created and the field artist_serie_id too but the index and foreign key don't.

I already created another blank project and it works (on sqlite) so probably it's a mysql adapter error.

Any idea?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I expect the root problem is that `series` is singular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series. That is, `serie` is not the singular form of `series`. It might be worth replacing `series` with `sequence`.

Comment: Yeah!!! That's the problem!! Thanks!

Comment: If you would like, create an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: I can't help but take you up on that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the root problem is that [`series` is singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series). That is, `serie` is not the singular form of `series`. It might be worth replacing `series` with `sequence`.